# How do I write the result of a Google Apps Script to a spreadsheet instead of log?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have a script that I am running that writes a Google Drive file inventory to a log using the `Logger.log()` method.

How would I modify this to write the result to a spreadsheet instead?

Comment: The checked answer below isnt complete. If you put more effort into the question (see s.o. guidelines) ill answer. Particularly because there are complete samples in the docs that seem you havent read.

Comment: Actually, that was the solution I was looking for. I had forgotten to create a new SpreadsheetApp instance before writing to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you wanting to just set rows in a column to be file names?

If you want each list to be a new sheet try

```
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create("File List");
```

I assume here you're iterating through the file list capturing one file name at a time. If you keep track of the last row you wrote to and increment that each time you should be able to call get range and get cell then set value something like this.

```
var currentRow = 0;
var range = ssNew.getRange(1, currentRow);
range.getCell(currentRow, 1).setValue(<file name>);
currentRow++;
```

With apps script sheets you're always getting a 'range' and never a cell in quite the way I think of it. Hope that helps

Comment: I created a new spreadsheet with Name in Column A, and ID in Column B. The issue I ran into is that the script times out if you don't pre-create the columns you wish to populate. Therefore, I added rows based on a mod of a counter variable, and used the `getLastRow()` method to check for the last row on the sheet at those various mod breakpoints. Also flushed the sheet for good measure so that the user (i.e. me) knows that the script is running. Ran into `"exceeded maximum execution time"` error. Trying to find a work-around for that now.

Comment: I'm sorry but you're in uncharted territory for me. I've got a script that dynamically creates a ton of sub menus from a list of keywords and takes over a couple seconds to execute but never ran into the max execution time error you're encountering. Is there a loop somewhere that doesn't complete, maybe? What do you see when you run the debug?

Comment: I just have too many files. Looking at options using the Advanced Drive Service API or JS/Python frameworks to solve the problem. Kind of a headache.

Comment: What sort of time frame are we talking about where it's failing? Could you maybe have it store file info in the sheet and place some kind of marker at the end that could be used by the script iterating over the files in the first place? .

Comment: See my other post if you are interested. In short, no. The index doesn't provide batch/paging tokenization. The Advanced API, however, does; as far as I can tell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645136/how-do-i-return-all-folder-names-and-ids-without-reaching-execution-limit