# How do I return all folder names and IDs without reaching execution limit?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am attempting to retrieve a list of all folders and their respective IDs using a Google Apps Script. Currently, I am writing the result to an array which is then posted to a spreadsheet every 5000 records. Unfortunately, the script reaches the execution limit (5 minutes) before completion. How can I work around this? And, would I have more success doing RESTful API calls over HTTP than using Apps Script?

I've noted the following:

1. Code already follows Google's bulk-writes best practice.
2. Slow execution is as a result of Apps Script indexing Drive slowly.
3. Results appear to follow a consistent indexing pattern.

   - Multiple runs produce results in same order
   - Unknown how items are re-indexed upon addition preventing meaningful caching between runs
   - Delta not reliable unless indexing method is identified
4. Looked into Drive caching.

   - Still required to loop through FolderIterator object
   - Theoretical performance would be even worse imo (correct?)

Code is below:

```
function LogAllFolders() {
  var ss_index = 1;
  var idx = 0;
  var folder;
  var data = new Array(5000);
  for (i=0;i<5000;i++){
    data[i] = new Array(2);
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("FolderInv2",1,2).getSheets()[0];
  var root = DriveApp.getFolders();
  while(root.hasNext()) {
    folder = root.next();
    data[idx][0] = folder.getName();
    data[idx][1] = folder.getId();
    idx++;
    if ((ss_index % 5000) == 0) {
      ss.insertRowsAfter(ss.getLastRow()+1, 5000);
      ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1,1,5000,2).setValues(data);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      idx = 0;
    }
    ss_index++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at the paging features of drive lists and combine with time based trigger

Answer (score 0):

I would first collect all the folder ids you wanted to process first, then you could save the folder ID (or maybe array index) that you've processed to your project properties and then run the job as a CRON every five minutes and just resume from that folder ID or index that you saved previously.

I guess when it's done, remove the CRON trigger programatically.